# MariaDB converting datetime string to date

Tags: sql, datetime, type-conversion, mariadb

[Trying CONVERT()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTHay.png)

[Trying STR_TO_DATE()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIxmj.png)

[Trying CAST() - neither DATE or DATETIME work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp1Y1.png)

[Trying CAST(STR_TO_DATE())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MSb1.png)

Hi, I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong with trying to convert my varchar column Procedure_Date containing a string in the dd/mm/YYYY hh:mm:ss format. I am trying to extract just the date from this string but I seem to be cursed. Using MariaDB and have gone through all the docs there. Greatly appreciate any advice!

Comment: You question states that your date format is `dd/mm/YYYY`. However your screen shot looks more like `mm/dd/YYYY`. Can you confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cast

```
SELECT Procedure_Date, CAST(STR_TO_DATE(Procedure_Date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS DATE) FROM uniTable5;
```

Comment: Cannot figure out why but using CAST() as DATE or DATETIME will not work. Updated post with a screenshot

Comment: I've re-edited the answer with ```CAST(STR_TO_DATE(Procedure_Date, '%d-%m-%Y')``` and this should work fine.

Comment: I think I might just be cursed. Updated my post with a screenshot - that is giving NULL as well. I do appreciate the help though

Comment: I would suggest that you should restart your server because the query actually works fine on my end

Comment: Still NULL - I'm chalking it up to me having committed crimes against SQL in a past life.

Comment: you funny! Kindly check your mariadb version, if <5.5, those query wont work

Comment: From the screen shot, the string should read `'%m/%d/%Y'`.

Comment: @pavis This may be more due to crimes against SQL in the current life. According to the screenshot, you have a hybrid date format which is not standard SQL or ISO8601 format. Where are the timestamps coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Use: DATE('YOUR DATETIME')

EXAMPLE: DATE('2022-04-25 14:50:01')

OUTPUT: 2022-04-25. Result in DATE.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are needed two steps to convert the `VARCHAR` into the `DATE`:

**First step** 
Convert the `VARCHAR` to `DATETIME` value using function [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/str_to_date/) with first parameter is the varchar string and second parameter of the `format` the varchar has.

In your example `01/31/2022 11:00:00` is having format equal to `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s'` so the full conversion is `STR_TO_DATE(Procedure_Date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')`

**Second step** 
Apply any [Date & Time Functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date-time-functions/) on the just converted varchar.

In your post you need to extract just the date so let's wrap the converted `datetime` value into the  [`DATE()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date-function/) function to get standard `Y-m-d` output format `DATE(STR_TO_DATE(Procedure_Date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s'))`, ie. `2022-01-31`.

If any other date time format is needed you may use function [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date_format/) with own definition of the `format` aka `'%Y-%m-%d'` that is equivalent of `Y-m-d` output format, ie. `2022-01-31`.

**Final query** 
Full query applied on examples from your screenshots would be:

```
SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE(Procedure_Date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')) as 'just_date' FROM uniTable5;
```

**Life query** 
Test life query in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96770d/4) I have created demotable with the code bellow:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `demotable` (
`datetimevarchar` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin'
) COLLATE='utf8_bin'ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `demotable` (`datetimevarchar`) VALUES 
     ('05/22/2023 08:22:45'),    ('05/23/2023 08:25:16'),    ('05/24/2023 11:06:21'),
     ('05/25/2023 11:06:21'),    ('05/26/2023 11:21:16'),    ('05/27/2023 11:26:10');

SELECT 
-- Original varchar value with readable date&time
datetimevarchar as 'original',
-- Conversion from varchar into DATETIME value
STR_TO_DATE(datetimevarchar, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') as 'full_date_time',
-- Applying Y-m-d from the DATETIME value
DATE(STR_TO_DATE(datetimevarchar, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')) as 'just_date',
-- Another example of date format
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(datetimevarchar, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s'), '%W, %d %M %Y') as 'verbative date'
FROM demotable;
```